# Squiz get asset id of current page out of nested content

Tags: content-management-system

I need some help with the Squiz Matrix CMS.

Basically I have a nested content for a box on my page. This box is included in via my paint layout and so on. Now, I need to get a dynamic link into this content, that I am loading. However, I cannot use the %asset_assetid% as it will only return my nested content id rather than the id of the actual page that is displayed.

I than need to get a specific metadata from the current page, or its parent page to get a specific value.

Hopefully that is more or less clear.

I would highly appreciate if you could help me.

All the best, 
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, what you are looking for is: `%globals_asset_assetid%`.

In future, you may find it easier and quicker to get the answer form either:

```
forums.squizsuite.net
```

or

```
manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net
```

Comment: Thank you : )Yes I recognised that Stackoverflow is not really good fo r Squiz :(